# Why is Python creating unnecessary copies of immutable objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, immutability

Say I create 2 lists:

```
l = range(pow(10,6))
m = range(pow(10,6))
```

Let's count the number of shared objects:

```
import itertools
sum(mi is li for mi, li in itertools.izip(m,l))

257
```

Only 257 out of one million? Mmh. Let's print them:

```
print [ mi for mi, li in itertools.izip(m,l) if mi is li ]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256]
```

Let's confirm that `257` is actually a different object in `m` and `l`:

```
m[257], l[257]

(257, 257)

id( m[257] ), id(l[257])

(4368166936, 4299261680)
```

I thought that for immutable types like integers or strings, Python was only creating references to a unique object, instead of creating multiple copies of the same object. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Python makes a tradeoff.

Only integers [between -5 and 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) are interned. Interning all integers rather than reaping them when no longer referenced can take too much memory, quite easily.

The range of -5 to 256 reflects the most commonly used integers across many types of Python programs; those integers would be created and destroyed many, many, many times otherwise, almost guaranteed.